# DatePicker with Time in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have used the datepicker object in flex to choose dates. I was wondering if anyone knew of any component that allowed the time to be picked from the same object.

For example something similar to [image]

from http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_inputDate.html

I have some space issues in my UI and this would really help. Does anyone know of a library for this sort of component

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of one.  You could create one.  Or if you have a budget; contact me and I'll create one for you.

Comment: thanks for the comments/answer. I'm not sure we have  budget so I might have to try and figure it out. If I manage something I might try and post code on here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any custom component which can suit your needs. You can develop your own custom component in Flex, by following UIComponent life cycle. Refer to any existing component e.g. Panel to understand it better. (You can find the source of the component in flex sdk folder)

Comment: thanks @Chetan-sachdev. Not sure who downvoted this but it was probably because it is more worthy of a comment than an answer. I'll checkout the component lifecycle as you suggested

Comment: I downvoted for exactly the reasons @RNJ guessed.  Sorry; I should have commented to explain myself.